# Mopub SDK : fetch creative name and details

Tags: android

I want to fetch Creative (Ad) Name or campaign name  which i have given at the time of new ad create.
How to I fetch using mo pub sdk in my android app.

Please suggest

Thanks 
--Gopal Sharma

Answer (score 0):

You can not fetch directly . for getting name you have to edit mo pub library and have to access HTML which loaded in Webview clint classes of mopub .
Parse this HTML you will aceess both mopub image URL aswell as creative ID.